# how to get percentage rounded to an integer

Tags: python, floating-point, int, percentage

Example:

```
150 blue balls
250 red balls
```

What are the percentage of blue balls?

150 divided by total balls (400) equals 38 percent

if I set it

```
blue_balls = 1.0 * number_of_blue_balls / (number_of_blue_balls + number_of_red_balls) * 100
```

I still get decimal (floating) and it's not rounded. 
I tried adding

```
int(round(float(blue_balls)))
```

with no luck

How do I get it to give me the answer in rounded integer form? no decimals

Thanks

Clarification- here's what I wrote

```
number_of_blue_balls = int(input('Enter number of blue balls:'))
number_of_red_balls = int(input('Enter number of red balls:'))

blue_balls= 1.0 * number_of_blue_balls / (number_of_blue_balls + number_of_red_balls) * 100
red_balls = 1.0 * number_of_red_balls / (number_of_blue_balls + number_of_red_balls) * 100

int(round(float(blue_balls)))
int(round(float(red_balls)))

print("Percent blue balls:", blue_balls,'%')
print("Percent red balls:", red_balls,'%')
```

I tried simplify the code and got the same answer, i just need one more line that converts the floating number into an integer/percent

1 number_of_blue_balls= int(input('Enter number of blue balls:'))

2 number_of_red_balls= int(input('Enter number of red balls:'))

3

4 blue_balls= int(number_of_blue_balls/ (number_of_blue_balls + number_of_red_balls) * 100

5 red_balls= int(number_of_red_balls/ (number_of_blue_balls + number_of_red_balls) * 100

6

7 print("Percent blue balls:", blue_balls)

8 print("Percent red balls:", red_balls)

FINALLY GOT IT!!! When I added .5 and couple sep='' I got the results I needed here it is

Thanks everyone!
1 number_of_blue_balls= int(input('Enter number of blue balls:'))

2 number_of_red_balls= int(input('Enter number of red balls:'))

3

4 blue_balls= int(number_of_blue_balls/ (number_of_blue_balls + number_of_red_balls) * 100 + 0.5)

5 red_balls= int(number_of_red_balls/ (number_of_blue_balls + number_of_red_balls) * 100)

6

7 print("Percent blue balls:", blue_balls, "%", sep='')

8 print("Percent red balls:", red_balls, "%", sep='')

Comment: That still doesn't work. My answers are still in floating form Here let me show you what I wrote specifically

Comment: What was the exact output?

Comment: I get output such as 100.0 % 0.0% and 37.5 % 62.5 % There are two problem, the decimal and the space between number and percent symbol

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
per = 1.0 * number_of_blue_balls / (number_of_blue_balls + number_of_red_balls) 
per = int(per * 100 + 0.5)
```

Comment: That worked, however it gets me results like this- blue balls - 37.5 and red balls has 62.5 so I end up with 38 and 63 totaling 101 percent. Now I have to figure how to make it so that both numbers equals 100

Comment: @PaulBernella if you only want to get integers, it's not always possible to have the sum to be equal 100. for instance, 150 and 250, then you get 38 and 63 too

Comment: @PaulBernella if the total must be 100%, use arithmetic that makes it so. `per_blue = int(per * 100 + 0.5)` `per_red = 100 - per_blue`

Comment: That doesn't quite work. I agree, it's algebraic, wish I thought of that. I'm sure that the second part is true (subtracting blue from 100 to get red) but I'm still struggling with getting the first equation to get me percentage that is rounded and integer (whole numbered)

Comment: @PaulBernella looking at your original code, you're not assigning the result of `int` to anything - perhaps you're still making that mistake?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.by assigning the result of int to anything

Comment: @PaulBernella instead of `int(...)` you need `blue_balls = int(...)`. The `=` is an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `math.ceil`

```
import math

print int(math.ceil(1.0*150 / (150+250) *100))
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it- the answer is

1 number_of_blue_balls= int(input('Enter number of blue balls:'))

2 number_of_red_balls= int(input('Enter number of red balls:'))

3

4 blue_balls= int(number_of_blue_balls/ (number_of_blue_balls + number_of_red_balls) * 100 + 0.5)

5 red_balls= int(number_of_red_balls/ (number_of_blue_balls + number_of_red_balls) * 100)

6

7 print("Percent blue balls:", blue_balls, "%", sep='')

8 print("Percent red balls:", red_balls, "%", sep='')

Comment: Using different rounding on the two values may work for this set of inputs but will fail on others. You have two conflicting requirements, rounding of the percentages and insisting that they add to 100 - one or the other must be relaxed.

Answer (score 0):

To get the answer in rounded integer percentage form:

Given `blue_balls, red_balls`:

```
denominator = blue_balls + red_balls
numerator = blue_balls
percent = (100 * numerator + denominator/2)/denominator
```